# How to prove that $3\mid F_n$ if and only if $4\mid n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fibonacci-numbers

I'm trying to prove my question using induction, first I tried to prove $4 \mid n \implies 3 \mid F_n$ and I got this:

Setting the base case at $n=0$ I get that $F_0=0\mid 3$ so I took the next $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that is divisible by $4$ that is $n=4$ and $F_4=1+2=3\mid 3$

Let $F_k$ such that $3 \mid F_k$, we'll prove that $3\mid F_{k+4}$

$F_{k+4}=F_{k+3}+F_{k+2}$

$=F_{k+2}+F_{k+1}+F_{k+1}+F_k$

$=F_{k+1}+F_k+F_{k+1}+F_{k+1}+F_k$

$=3F_{k+1}+2F_k$

Since $3 \mid F_k$ by hypothesis then $3 \mid 2F_k$

Clearly $3 \mid 3F_{k+1}$

Here I don't know how to follow, since, for me, it seems that the proof is done. However there's still one implication left, but I don't know how to start it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can find the residues of $F_k$ mod $3$ and show they are periodic with induction.

Comment: Yeah I've read about that. But what about my proof, am I on the right way is it complete already? I don't wanna use more results in my proof in that I'd also have to prove those.

Comment: You haven't finished writing a proof, since you only proved one direction. You haven't proved $3$ does *not* divide $F_k$ when $4$ doesn't divide $k$. I.e. that $F_k\not\equiv 0$ mod $3$ when $k\equiv 1,2,3$ mod $4$. But in using induction to prove $F_k\not\equiv 0$ mod $3$ (for certain $k$), you will need to know the actual residues of $F_{k-1}$ and $F_{k-2}$ mod $3$. You say you "don't wanna" prove more stuff, but too bad.

Comment: So what I actually proved was that if $3$ divides $F_k$ then $4$ divides $k$?. I didn't say that "I didn't want" to prove more things in the way you understood, I just thought there were other ways to prove it.

Comment: $$F_n\mid F_m \iff n\mid m$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fibonacci sequence divisible by 3?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1478582/fibonacci-sequence-divisible-by-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working mod $3$, the Fibonacci series is $$1,1,2,0,2,2,1,0,1,1,2,0,\ldots$$

It is easy to prove that this has period $8$, as shown above, with every fourth term being zero, and all the others being nonzero.

Comment: How'd you get that though? I'm not supposed to use results without proving them.

Comment: @andrespm By a similar token you can prove that $3|F_{k+8}-F_k$ for all $k$.

Comment: The twelve I've displayed is simply the first twelve, by calculation.  The key to the proof that this repeats is that once you have two values in a row repeat, then everything must repeat from then on.  That is, since you started with $1,1$, then as soon as you get $1,1$ again it must repeat because the defining recurrence goes back two steps.